# Running Python Script via Task Scheduler returns weird characters in JSON File

Tags: python, windows-server-2016, windows-task-scheduler

I'm running a Python Script ("run whether user is logged on or not") on Windows Server 2016 every hour.

The Python Script basically just calls an API and exports the results into the JSON file. The problem is, that sometimes JSON file contains weird characters in a few fields. For example, "7494690" would be displayed as "�Qޘ'".

If I'm logged into the server via RDP, then files are coming out fine 10 out of 10 times. If I'm logged out and tasks run automatically, then most often (not always!) I get weird characters - roughly 8-9 times out of 10.

I've changed the user, but the issue persists. Any ideas..?

Edit:
There's a new symptom. I've added the same task on a task scheduler twice. On the first attempt, I'm getting a corrupted file. On the second attempt, the file turns out fine. Could it be that Windows somehow picks up the the wrong locale/encoding?

Comment: What program you use to open/check that json file?

Comment: Just checking it on Notepad. There's also C# script that later picks up the file.

Comment: Is the whole file corrupted or only part? You may be experiencing some form of this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690349/strange-utf8-decoding-error-in-windows-notepad

Comment: Only part. It's a massive nested JSON file, but only a few fields are affected.

Comment: So, it's not a problem with displaying the content of a file but the file itself is corrupted? 
Are the same fields corrupted every time? Maybe the way of processing fields is affected by user locale?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to test if the problem is with displaying the content of a file or the file itself is corrupted. Every time I run the script interactively, the JSON string is fine. I'm not too sure how to check the JSON string without writing it to the file when the task is being ran automatically. The same fields are corrupted every time. I do lean towards the hypothesis that API and Python scripts are fine, but something's funny going on our server. If the same task is ran twice, the first one generates corrupted file, and the second is fine...